# How to fix the callback was already called in loopback model

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I have tried to extend api in loopback model.
In the model, I used standard api of model such as findOne, create.
The example codes are below

```
Subscriber.findOne({
 where : {
      email : "............."
 },
 function(err, instance){
      if(instance)
      {
           cb(null,instance);
           response = "success";
      }
 }
 cb(null, response);
```

But when I called this extended api, the error was occurred.

```
throw err:// Rethron non-MsSQL errors
    ^

Error: Callback was already called.
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `return` inside the `if` callback as you haven't used `else` statement. Change your code to:

```
Subscriber.findOne({
  where: {
    email: "............."
  },
  function(err, instance) {
    if (instance) {
      response = "success";
      return cb(null, instance);
    }
  },
  return cb(null, response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A better code:

```js
Subscriber.findOne({
  where: {
    email: "............."
  },
  (err, instance) => {
    if (err) return cb(err)
    
    if (!instance) {
      let error = new Error()
      error.status = 404
      error.message = 'Subscriber not found.'

      return cb(error)
    }
      
    cb(null, instance)
  }
})
```